# git create binary file upon checkout

Tags: git

I am trying to create files upon `git checkout`, for example create the pdf from a tex file or an image from an asymptote source file.
I know that I can just checkout the source files and then process them by hand, but I would prefer this done automatically. So far I tried playing with the smudge filter, but it seems that smudge can only modify the source file and not create a new binary file. Any ideas on how to create a binary from a source file during checkout?

My unsuccessful smudge filter for processing asymptote files. Works well if called in shell directly, but not via git:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1
asy $1 >/dev/null
```

Comment: The working directory (`getcwd()`) of a smudge filter is unspecified, so opening files by path name will get you a file in some unknown location within the file system. (i.e., don't do that.) Consider using a post-checkout hook; the working directory of these hooks is well-defined (but not necessarily where you were when you ran `git checkout`).

Comment: I'd say you're misusing the version control system. Use a makefile to trigger builds explicitly, it isn't that much more typing.

Comment: Indeed, makefiles are the solution. Now my post-checkout hook only calls make and this will take care of everything. No more accidentally working with outdated graphics and other goodies :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with @torek's comment I managed to find a somewhat working solution by creating my own post-checkout hook. This hook (in `.git/hooks/post-checkout`) will run asymptote on all *.asy files after a checkout. So it is not only running on the files being checked out and might therefore become rather slow in a large project with many asymptote files. But it works somehow and I hope it will be useful to someone else, too.

```
#!/bin/bash

printf '\npost-checkout hook\nregenerates all asymptote files\n'

# Now find all files ending with .asy and run asymptote on them:
find . -type f -name '*.asy' -execdir asy \{\} \;
# Note that this will recompile ALL asymptote files, not only the possibly changed ones.
# This is because I have no clue on how to check what changed during checkout.
```